# Media Gallery module field settings stored in database?

Tags: 7, media

I have installed the [Media Gallery](http://drupal.org/project/media_gallery) module for someone's site to upload fotoalbums with; it's need to add a file size restriction because quite a bit of pictures are coming in.
I can't tell what the exact error is in English; the site's language is Dutch. When I want to edit fields in my Media Gallery content type, I get a message that says the settings are stored in the database, locked and I can't change those settings anymore.

**Update:** There is a [similar issue at Drupal.org](http://drupal.org/node/1202642); it looks like it isn't possible. Or is it?

Comment: Whats your Question ?

Comment: I would like to change the settings but I can't

Comment: There is a configuration page for sure. Take a look at tuts here http://www.drupalgardens.com/documentation/gallery

Comment: This is a tutorial for those who want to install and use Media Gallery. What I need is to edit the cck fields of the content type as posed in my question: "But when I want to edit fields in my Media Gallery content type..."

Comment: also the answer http://drupal.org/node/1202642#comment-5073842

Comment: I'll quote from that comment: "This is a dirty solution without language checking, just really quickfix". Thus not a real solution and one that needs custom php for any specific thing you want to change and I can't write that kind of php.

Comment: ...I'm sort of in the same boat as the poster of http://drupal.org/node/1202642#comment-5677824

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make the 'dirty solution' from the link posted by @NikhilMohan into a more 'clean' one pretty easily:

```
function MYMODULE_form_media_gallery_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  if (arg(1) == 'add') {
    // Get the language code from the node object. Should be reliable.
    $langcode = $form['#node']->language;

    $form['settings_wrapper']['presentation']['media_gallery_allow_download'][$langcode]['#default_value'] = 0;
  }
}
```

If you're not comfortable writing a custom module you can easily drop this function into your theme's template.php file instead, but change the name of the function to `MYTHEME_form_media_gallery_node_form_alter`. Once you clear Drupal's caches the hook will start to be called.

Don't forget that Media Gallery is still in beta so you have to expect a few bugs/missing configuration options. Using hooks to alter the fields you need to is pretty much the only option you have here, without going directly into the database.

Comment: Awesome. So yes it's beta and hasn't been updated since okt2011 so it looks like brave php attempts are needed